# Is there a service to legally stream football games?

Tags: american-football, nfl, media

I have a Roku TV and no cable. I understand this is on Fox, but I can't find any useful information on their website about what I need to buy or subscribe to in order to watch this live. I see how to watch old games with NFL Game Pass, and I see how I could watch last year's game on CBS, but nothing about this year.

Is there some kind of online subscription or other service I can purchase (anything other than a traditional cable service) in order to legally watch the live game on my Roku TV? (I can also use Google Cast with the TV, if that helps).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it requests either information that should be obtained directly from the provider, or information on how to break laws.

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it _illegally_, that's easy to do. 

I'm asking how to do it legally and as I mentioned in the question, I've already checked the provider's site, but all the NFL and Fox sites talk about is how to stream Sunday games and Thursday night games. Thanksgiving day games aren't mentioned.

Comment: Nij, I appreciate the attention you've given my question which has obviously caused you so much frustration. I was under the impression that the purpose of this site was to ask questions about sports. I'm sure every answer to this site could be achieved by contacting experts over the phone or via email, but then why would we have any of the sites in the SE network?

Comment: Oversimplification of how Stack Exchange works doesn't support your point. Plenty of questions about sports are closed every week.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nlj. In your view, which types of sports questions are appropriate for this site?

Comment: [This](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1525) is a similar question (which was revised to avoid sounding like a [source request](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). If things are the same as they were in 2012, then "there is no 'legal' way to watch live streaming NFL games online without going through a cable provider" (which [your answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15006) seems to support). However, considering there has been Super Bowl streaming since, that may have changed.

Comment: Last year for Thanksgiving, streaming was possible via Fox Sports Go (but not without providing your cable provider). http://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-to-watch-nfl-football-on-thanksgiving/

Comment: Thanks @MASTERMIND_ED, I've edited my question to make it clear that I'm looking for legal options and that I'm happy to pay for a service like Sling, I just don't want to go through a a traditional cable provider.

Comment: If nothing else, this question may be a duplicate of [a question about how the NFL distributes content online](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/how-does-the-nfl-distribute-their-content-online), given the information is as valid today as it was almost seven years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with a few friends, I found two options.

1. Buy an HD Antennae and use that to watch the game on a local affiliate.
2. Another possibility is to pick up a either an orange or blue subscription from SlingTV. The orange subscription says it will let you watch Sunday games, and the blue apparently adds Thursday night, but I couldn't find confirmation anywhere about Thanksgiving day games.

So as far as I can tell, the best option is the $20 antennae on Amazon.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the Thanksgiving day game isn't included in the Twitter deal :(

https://nflcommunications.com/Pages/2016-'Thursday-Night-Football'-Broadcast-Schedule-Announced.aspx